# Set variable from inside composition file vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm beginning with composition API in Vue and I don't know if I'm breaking some pattern by doing things the way I'm doing.

I would like to set a variable from inside the composition file itself:

**GameLogic.ts**

```js
export default function () {
  ...
    
  const buildMovieGuessed = (movie: Movie, score: number) => ({ ...movie, score });

  const addNewMovieGuessing = (movie: Movie, score: number) => {
    // The variable moviesGuessed is not being set. In my template it still stays a
    // an empty array
    moviesGuessed = [buildMovieGuessed(movie, score), ...moviesGuessed];

    currentStep.value += 1;
  };

  return {
    originalMovies,
    activeTerm,
    currentStep,
    activeMovie,
    guessingScore,
    moviesGuessed,
    addNewMovieGuessing,
  };
}
```

From the Vue component I call

**GuessMovie.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api';
import GameLogic from '@/services/composition/game/GameLogic';
import { ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate';
import BInputWithValidation from '@/components/_buefy/BInputWithValidation.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    ValidationObserver,
    BInputWithValidation,
  },
  setup() {
    const {
      originalMovies,
      activeTerm,
      currentStep,
      activeMovie,
      guessingScore,
      moviesGuessed,
      addNewMovieGuessing,
    } = GameLogic();

    return {
      originalMovies,
      activeTerm,
      currentStep,
      activeMovie,
      guessingScore,
      moviesGuessed,
      addNewMovieGuessing,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onAddNewMovieGuessingClick() {
      // I call the action from here  
      this.addNewMovieGuessing(this.activeMovie.value, this.guessingScore.value);
    },
  },
  created() {
    // @todo: handle the case if there are no movies
  },
});
</script>
```

How can I set up the variable `moviesGuessed` from inside the `GameLogic.ts` so that I can keep the logic in a central place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `addNewMovieGuessing()` reassigns `moviesGuessed`, you're losing the reference to the original value.

It looks like you're trying to insert the new movie guess into the first position of the `moviesGuessed` array. You could use [`Array.prototype.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to do that without losing reactivity:

```js
// BEFORE:
moviesGuessed = [buildMovieGuessed(movie, score), ...moviesGuessed];

// AFTER:
moviesGuessed.unshift(buildMovieGuessed(movie, score));
```